# Windows 8.1 : Create "silent" toast notification

Tags: notifications, windows-8.1, toast

I'm working on a Windows app and integrated Toast notification in it. Paired with an AWS SNS service, it's working fine, I can successfully receive my notifications.

My notifications are used to fire events when the app is launched, it's not designed for final user. For this reason, I don't need any banner or display for these notifications: only handle  the event in the app.

My issue is, when the app is killed, Windows displays a banner (top right corner) for any new notification. I found a way to disable banners directly in the OS, but I would like a solution when pushing the notification (backend side).

I already did it for iOS, kind of 'silent' notification, without any alert, sound or badge, but can still be handled by the OS.

I would like to know if there is any way to do that on Windows too? Like any extra arguments I missed or a dedicated template for that.

Thanks

Comment: Toasts and notifications are meant for users, not internal events. Perhaps there is a better way to do what you are doing.

Comment: If there is another way to register to server side events and forward them to a mobile app, I will be glad to hear it. I can unsubscribe to event when after my user logged out, but not when he killed the app, that's why I need "silent" notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way to do that.

I changed from Toast notification to Raw notification (a push notification that does not involve UI). (MSDN - [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.pushnotifications.rawnotification.aspx))

After that, I had to customise my AWS SNS notification wiht MessageAttributes to change the type of my WNS notification (AWS - [Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMessageAttributes.html)).

I've also noticed that we can directly suppress the Toast UI on Windows phone with "*X-WNS-SuppressPopup*" param, which can be also very helpful. (MSDN - [SuppressPopup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465435.aspx#pncodes_x_wns_suppresspopup)).

Finally, inspired from [AWS Baidu Push notification sample code](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMobilePushBaiduPublish.html), I did the same for WNS platform, adding all new arguments I needed, and it works great at the end.

Hope this can help someone else.